# How to write every nth calculation to an array inside a for loop? (python)

Tags: python, arrays, loops, data-storage

I'm running a simulation in python that involves many many loops. Since my laptop has limited processing power, I want to write only every nth result to an array which stores my data. I looked online about slicing arrays, but could only find how to do it once a full-sized array had already been created. The for loop is below:

```
    def Simulate(time, steps):

            history_x = np.zeros(2000000)
            history_y = np.zeros(2000000)

            for i in range(2000000):
                    #calculate positions
                    a_x = ((-6.67e-11)*(mE)/((x**2 + y**2)))
                    a_y = ((-6.67e-11)*(mE)/((x**2 + y**2)))
                    v_x = v_x + (delta_t)*a_x
                    v_y = v_y + (delta_t)*a_y
                    y = y + (delta_t)*v_y + ((delta_t)**2)*a_y*0.5
                    x = x + (delta_t)*v_x + ((delta_t)**2)*(a_x)*0.5

                    rocket_history_x[i] = x
                    rocket_history_y[i] = y
```

(x,y, v_x, v_y and mE are all defined before the loop in my code, didn't want to clutter this post)

Essentially the maths isn't important, but I want history_x and history_y to only store every nth calculation of x and y. How do I do this?

Comment: Where does rocket_history_x comes from?

Comment: If you're only storing part of the indices then `history_x/y` doesn't have to have size 2000000. And just use an `if` to store certain indices.

Comment: So you only want to run the loop for values of `i` divisible by `n`?

Comment: See the third parameter of https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range .

Comment: Out of `2000000` let's say you want to write every 10000th value, you can do `if i%10000 == 0`, and then save `rocket_history_x.append(x)` and `rocket_history_y.append(y)`. In this case, you will have to start with empty lists as `history_x = []` and `history_y = []`

Comment: just do `for i in range(startingnumber, 2000000, steps):`

Comment: @cryptonome: The positions need to be updated at each step, only the storing of values needs to be done every nth step

Comment: @Bazingaa hmm i see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment above, a complete code would look like below. Here you initialize two empty lists instead of creating an array of length 2000000. Then you just save every nth value based on the if condition by enclosing the `append` statement within the `if` statements.

```
def Simulate(time, steps):
    history_x, history_y = [[] for _ in range(2)] # initialize lists
    n = 10000
    for i in range(2000000):
        #calculate positions
        a_x = ((-6.67e-11)*(mE)/((x**2 + y**2)))
        a_y = ((-6.67e-11)*(mE)/((x**2 + y**2)))
        v_x = v_x + (delta_t)*a_x
        v_y = v_y + (delta_t)*a_y
        y = y + (delta_t)*v_y + ((delta_t)**2)*a_y*0.5
        x = x + (delta_t)*v_x + ((delta_t)**2)*(a_x)*0.5
        if i% n == 0: # Check for the step
            rocket_history_x.append(x) # store x here
            rocket_history_y.append(y) # store y here
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much - just checked that and it works!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check such as:

```
if i%n == 0:
```